# Problemas con weka en python

Tags: python

cuando quiero convertir en python un archivo .csv en uno .arff uso una funcion que me tira este error

> "No visible constructors for class (weka.core.converters.Loader)"

Alguna solucion ? o otra forma de convertir .csv en .arff en python?

```
from weka.core.converters import Loader , Saver

def guardarArff(self):
    loader = Loader(classname="weka.core.converters.CSVLoader")
    data = loader.load_file("C:/Users/usuario/Desktop/jythonproject/archivo/media/documents/wine_quality.csv")
    saver = Loader(classname="weka.core.converters.ArffSaver")
    saver.save_file("C:/Users/usuario/Desktop/jythonproject/archivo/media/documents/wine_quality.arff")
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto es por que `weka.core.converters.ArffSaver` no pertenece a `Loader` si no a `Saver` , Su programa quedaría de la siguiente forma.

```
import os
from weka.core.converters import Loader , Saver
import weka.core.jvm as jvm

def main():
    loader = Loader(classname="weka.core.converters.CSVLoader")
    data = loader.load_file("C:/Users/usuario/Desktop/jythonproject/archivo/media/documents/wine_quality.csv")
    saver = Saver(classname="weka.core.converters.ArffSaver") 
    saver.save_file(data,"C:/Users/usuario/Desktop/jythonproject/archivo/media/documents/wine_quality.arff")


if __name__ == "__main__":
try:
    jvm.start()
    main()
except Exception, e:
    print(e)
finally:
    jvm.stop()
```

Comment: me sigue diciendo lo mismo , el problema esta en la linea "loader = Loader(classname="weka.core.converters.CSVLoader")"

Comment: Actualizé mi respuesta. Comprobar.